# Return serializable object from Spring entity

Tags: json, spring, return, entity, serializable

I have a Entity with two variables String value, and String description.

I need for front-end, to return list of objects in the next format (with " " for every object value), in order to be easy for JSON validation for front-end.

WANTED:

```
{"value":"WRITTEN_PRODUCTION","description" : "Written production"},
```

I have currently overridden the "toString" method in my entity to the following:

```
 @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" + "value :" + value + ", description :'" + description + "'" + '}';
    }
```

but, I am not receiving the wanted format. I am receiving without " ", or the next:
 {value:'WRITTEN_PRODUCTION',description : 'Written production'},

I tried escaping characters \" in "toString" but it's not working in the format I want. If I am using \" before each " " in the return is also giving the \ and that's not what I want.
Any suggestions or advice how to get the following format:

```
  {"value":"WRITTEN_PRODUCTION","description" : "Written production"},
```

Comment: Are you returning from controller?

Comment: Are you using spring boot? if yes return the Entity object from controller directly you dont need any overridden toString() method.

Comment: Yes I am returning from controller with MediaType JSON, but the format is not as I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toString()` Method

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "{" + "\"value\" :\"" + value + "\", \"description\" :\"" + description + "\"" + '}';
}
```

**Output in console using sysout:**

```
{"value" :"abc", "description" :"des"}
```

Comment: I am returning from controller with MediaType JSON, but the format is not as I wanted. I have tried using the \ as escape before each ", as \", but when I get the response is showing also the \ in it ?

Comment: If you are returning from controller then no need to override toString() method.

Comment: It turn out that I don't need to override methods in my entity. I have posted a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I was complicating the stuff more than they are. 
I don't need overridden methods, but only simple  getters, setters and constructor. The rest is done by the controller. I got in mistaken the direction by wanting to get unique overridden "toString()" method.